# Angular unit test never reaches the assertion

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I have a search input field that invokes a component method ('searchBooks') as soon as a value is typed.

**html**:

```
<form [formGroup]="searchForm">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput type="search" formControlName="term"/>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

**component**:

```
export class BookSearchComponent implements OnInit {
  searchForm = this.fb.group({
    term: ''
  });

  ...

  ngOnInit() {
    this.searchForm.get('term').valueChanges
    .subscribe(() => this.searchBooks()); // this subscription will listen to any value changes on the input field
  }

  searchBooks() {
     // does something
  }
```

I'm attempting to write a unit test that checks if the 'searchBooks' method gets called after a value is entered in the input field. When I tried the following attempt, *the test never reaches the assertion*:

**spec file:**

```
describe('Search for Books', () => {
  let component: BookSearchComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<BookSearchComponent>;
  let searchInputField: ElementRef;
  let searchBooks: jasmine.Spy;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [BooksFeatureModule, NoopAnimationsModule, SharedTestingModule]
    }).compileComponents();

    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BookSearchComponent);
    searchInputField = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input'));
    searchBooks = spyOn(component, 'searchBooks');
    fixture.detectChanges();
  }));

  ...

  it('searchBooks method should be called after a value is entered in the search field', () => {
    searchInputField.nativeElement.value = 'Harry Potter';
    searchInputField.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(component.searchBooks).toHaveBeenCalled(); // <--- Test runner never gets to this assertion!
    });
  });
```

Any suggestions on a practical way to test the aforementioned behavior? (typing value in input field triggers searchBooks method)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to take advantage of the `done` callback to let Angular/Jasmine know when you're done with the test. It won't go inside of the `then` block because it is asynchronous and the test will complete before the callback happens.

Try:

```
it('searchBooks method should be called after a value is entered in the search field', (done) => { // add done call back as argument
    searchInputField.nativeElement.value = 'Harry Potter';
    searchInputField.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(component.searchBooks).toHaveBeenCalled(); // <--- Test runner never gets to this assertion!
      done(); // call done letting jasmine know I am done with my assertions
    });
  });
```

You can also do it in an `async/await` way (I prefer this way):

```
it('searchBooks method should be called after a value is entered in the search field', async () => { // add async here
    searchInputField.nativeElement.value = 'Harry Potter';
    searchInputField.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    await fixture.whenStable(); // wait until the fixture is stable
    expect(component.searchBooks).toHaveBeenCalled(); // <--- Test runner never gets to this assertion!
  });
```

Also, since you're using reactive forms, a big proponent of reactive forms is to simplify testing. You can use JavaScript to set the value of the form and do your assertions and you don't have to mess with the DOM.

```
it('searchBooks method should be called after a value is entered in the search field', () => { 
    let term = component.searchForm.controls['term'];
    term.setValue('Harry Potter');
    expect(component.searchBooks).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```